# Approximate number of colors in Bitmap

Tags: c#, colors, bitmap, heuristics

I'm looking for an approximate algorithm returning an approximate number of colors in an Image - possibly stopping when a Min number is reached.

The language is C#, and I'm working on Bitmap objects. An idea is to iterate over all pixels, but this can be very time expensive.

Any ideas?

Comment: You could take a number of samples, maybe until the numbers stabilze. note that color equality is an issue of its own..

Comment: Iterating over all pixels isn't _that_ slow, as long as you use `LockBits` and not `GetPixel`.

Comment: If you need an optimized solution, you could use the [ColorCountCommand Class](https://www.leadtools.com/help/sdk/v22/dh/pc/colorcountcommand.html) from LEADTOOLS. (Disclosure: I work for the vendor). I tested with a 32-megapixel image that contains 149980 unique colors, and it took 65 milliseconds to calculate the exact count. The test was done on a somewhat old Intel Core i7-4790 processor. If you would like to try this class, you can download the free evaluation of LEADTOOLS [from this page](https://www.leadtools.com/downloads).